# why terminal output can't be saved to file when there's core dumped

Tags: coredump, tee

I'm running an executable and trying to save terminal output to a file:

```html
# ll
total 132
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   496 Jun 14 11:41 mpx-debug.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 12775 Jun 14 11:41 mpx-dig.c
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  3526 Jun 14 11:41 mpx-hw.h
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 65176 Jun 14 14:28 mpx-mini-test
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 40480 Jun 14 11:41 mpx-mini-test.c
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   205 Jun 14 11:41 mpx-mm.h
# ./mpx-mini-test
XSAVE is supported by HW & OS
XSAVE processor supported state mask: 0x1f
XSAVE OS supported state mask: 0x1f
 BNDREGS: size: 64 user: 1 supervisor: 0 aligned: 0
  BNDCSR: size: 64 user: 1 supervisor: 0 aligned: 0
no MPX support
Aborted (core dumped)
#
# ./mpx-mini-test | tee -a mpx-mini-test.log
#
# cat mpx-mini-test.log
#
```

As you can see, there're some prints in terminal without "| tee -a **.log".
But with "| tee -a **.log", nothing is saved to file.

I suspect it has something to do with the "Abort (core dumped)", did some googling but can't figure out exactly why. Is there anyone knows why? And how could I save all terminal outputs(including the "Abort (core dumped)") to file? Thanks in advance.